# ListObjectsResponse is truncated but NextMarker is null

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm following the example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html

I'm getting an endless loop over the same 1000 keys here.  Why is response.NextMarker null in the first iteration (and every iteration) of the while loop if response.Truncated = true?

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client("accessKey", "secretKey");

var request = new ListObjectsRequest().WithBucketName(bucket).WithPrefix(prefix);

            do
            {
                ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

                foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("key = {0} size = {1}",
                        entry.Key, entry.Size);
                }

                if (response.IsTruncated)
                {
                    request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
                }
                else
                {
                    request = null;
                }
            } while (request != null);
```

Comment: What does the response.NextMarker say?

Comment: response.NextMarker is null.  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part in the subject. Anyway, that's strange is all I can say. If you continue to observe the same behavior the best shot would be to post the details in AWS forums with details and someone from AWS can check the logs that they's have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed when I updated to a newer AWSSDK.dll